# Не получается установить vue (npm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, vue.js

Привет. Мне нужно установить vue. Я это делаю ровно так, как сказано [здесь](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/installation.html). Но в силу того, что я не силён в nmp, не могу быстро сообразить, что не так делаю. Мне выпадает лог:

```
urvanov@wks-urvanov:~$ sudo npm install vue-router
/home/INT.PV.KM/urvanov
└── vue-router@2.3.1 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/INT.PV.KM/urvanov/package.json'
npm WARN urvanov No description
npm WARN urvanov No repository field.
npm WARN urvanov No README data
npm WARN urvanov No license field.
```

Я попытался разобраться, что от меня хочет `nmp`. Нашёл [статейку](https://habrahabr.ru/post/133363/). Но, увы, даже после предлагаемого способа установки nmp (и обновления), ничего не поменялось. Из этой статейки я выполнил: `npm install npm -g`.

Что я делаю не так? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не хватает package.json. Этот файл должен находится в корне проекта. 
Как составлять этот файл можно найти в документации [документации](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json). Вы же можете создать с минимальными настройками.

```
    {
  "name": "zona",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",


  "dependencies": {

  },
  "devDependencies": {

  }
}
```

и сделать `sudo npm install vue-router --save`, это запишет в Ваш файл package.json зависимость.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот вариант, мне помог.

Очистка кеша

```
npm --force
```

Сама установка

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Comment: как вариант, посмотрите объем свободной памяти (если это виртуальный сервер)